# Convert a table to database MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table which is contain many items and many users

Here is the table

```
           ------------------------------------------
           |    Item1   |    Item2    |     Item3   |
-----------------------------------------------------
| U1like   |     1      |      0      |      0      |
-----------------------------------------------------
| U1dislake|     0      |      1      |      1      |
-----------------------------------------------------
| U2like   |     1      |      1      |      1      |
-----------------------------------------------------
| U2dislike|     0      |      0      |      1      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

1 and 0 is boolean. It means that 1 means to Userx rated the item and 0 means that Usex is not rated the item.

ex:

U1like rated the Item1 is 1, means u1 rated the Item1 as like

U2dislike rated the Item3 is 1, means U2 rated the Item3 as dislike

U1like rated the Item2 is 0, means U1 not rated at all

I don't have any idea how to convert it to database. Can someone help me?
thank you

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a table where you store the users (let's name it USERS for now) and every user have an ID. Therefore you have an another table with the items (ITEMS) with an ID too.

So you have to create a table USER_VOTES like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_VOTES(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
USER_ID INT,
ITEM_ID INT,
VOTE BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
KEY(USER_ID),
KEY(ITEM_ID),
KEY(USER_ID,ITEM_ID));
```

And if a user vote you can insert that into this table or you can check for a vote with a select statement.

```
SELECT VOTE FROM USER_VOTES WHERE (USER_ID=1) AND (ITEM_ID=2);
```

If you would like to see all votes, you can easily sum from it:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM(VOTE) FROM USER_VOTES GROUP BY ITEM_ID ORDER BY ITEM_ID;
```

To have Likes and Dislikes separated, use:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM(IF(VOTE=1,1,0)) AS "Likes", SUM(IF(VOTE=0,1,0)) AS "DisLikes"
FROM USER_VOTES GROUP BY ITEM_ID ORDER BY ITEM_ID;
```

Or you can join the USERS and ITEMS table with this to get what you want:

```
SELECT USERS.NAME, ITEMS.NAME, USER_VOTES.VOTE FROM 
USER_VOTES 
LEFT JOIN USERS ON (USERS.ID=USER_VOTES.USER_ID)
LEFT JOIN ITEMS ON (ITEMS.ID=USER_VOTES.ITEM_ID)
ORDER BY USERS.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple tables

- User
- Rating
- Item

User contains your user information and a unique ID

Rating contains the userId, itemId and the rating, the rating value can be 0 for dislike and 1 for like

Items contains the item information and an unique ID